# Query to check if many-to-many relation exists

Tags: mysql

I have one of these moments when something seems so simple but I just can't seem to find the right query. I am looking for a query that checks if a certain many-to-many relation already exists. Consider the following table:

```
    +---------+---------+
    | feed_id | coll_id |
    +---------+---------+
    |       1 |       1 |
    |       1 |       2 |
    |       1 |       3 |
    +---------+---------+
```

It's a table from a many to many relation between a table 'feeds' and a table 'collections'.

I need a query that checks if a feed already exists that has collections 1 and 2, and ONLY 1 and 2. If there is, I would need its feed_id.

In the above table this feed does not exist.

A more generic description of the query would be: find a feed that contains all of the coll_id's, and that the feed doesn't contain any other collections. This would mean the following for the example above:

1. making sure that coll_id is IN(1,2)
2. making sure that a COUNT(*) WHERE feed_id = 1 would return 2 (the number of coll_id's)

What's problematic in step 2 is that I don't have the value of the feed_id available in my sub query.

Or am I completely on the wrong track?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will answer all the situations:

```
SELECT coll_id, feed_id
FROM a a1
GROUP BY coll_id
HAVING feed_id IN (2,4)
AND COUNT(*) = 2
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM a a2
    WHERE a2.coll_id = a1.coll_id
    AND feed_id NOT IN (2,4)
)
```

I did my tests with these data:

```
+---------+---------+
| feed_id | coll_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |
|       2 |       4 |
|       2 |       7 |
|       3 |       3 |
|       4 |       2 |
|       4 |       4 |
|       5 |       4 |
|       6 |       1 |
|       6 |       2 |
|       6 |       4 |
|       7 |       2 |
|       7 |       4 |
+---------+---------+
```

Only coll_id 4 and 7 has only 2 and 4 as feed_id

I also did the test with feed_id (1,2,4) returns 6 and feed_id (3) returns 3

Patrick

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this query, and I assume you have a UNIQUE key on both columns:

```
SELECT feed_id
FROM t
WHERE feed_id = 1 AND coll_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY feed_id
HAVING COUNT(coll_id) = 2
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I don't know the feed_id. I query this table with IN(1,2) and it should return me 0 rows, because I am looking for a feed with 'exactly' coll_id's 1 and 2. Feed_id 1 should not be returned, because is also has coll_id = 3. If I do the same query with IN(1,2,3), then it should return feed_id 1.

Comment: Wait, do you need the list of _all_ the `feed_id`s that have only coll 1 and 2?

Comment: I just ran a quick test. It works if you do `IN(1,2,3)` and then `HAVING COUNT(coll_id) = 3` (this count should be the number of items you have in the `IN`). If you don't want to restrict to a single `feed_id`, you can just remove `feed_id = 1 AND` from the query, and it will return a list of `feed_id`s that match the criteria.

Comment: I tried that one, but it's problematic too because if I do <pre>IN(1,2)</pre> and <pre>HAVING COUNT(coll_id) = 2</pre>, it sill returns feed_id 1, while it shouldn't

Comment: I just tested something else that works, not sure how efficient this is though: SELECT DISTINCT feed_id FROM t WHERE coll_id IN (1,2,3) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t WHERE coll_id NOT IN(1,2,3))

Comment: You mean something like this? `SELECT DISTINCT feed_id FROM t WHERE coll_id IN (1,2,3) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t t2 WHERE t.feed_id = t2.feed_id AND coll_id NOT IN(1,2,3))`

Comment: Haven't tested it yet, but I'll let you know if that worked. Thanks!